# Loading Custom Component ViewModel from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a custom component loader within `knockout` but I'm struggling with the view model. Essentially I want to remotely go grab both the HTML template and the JavaScript view model, but in this instance I don't want to use a traditional AMD module loader.

I've managed to get some of this working, specifically loading the HTML template but I can't figure out how to load the view model. Before I start here's my directory structure:

-- index.html
-- customerLoader.js
-- comps
      -- myCustom.html
      -- myCustom.js

So I've created my component loader like so. `getConfig` basically takes the name of the component and turns that into a path for the viewModel and the html template.

```
var customLoader = {
    getConfig: function(name, callback) {
        callback({ template: "comps/" + name + ".html", viewModel: "comps/" + name + ".js" });
    },
    loadTemplate: function(name, templateConfig, callback) {
        console.log("loadTemplate", name, templateConfig);
        $.get(templateConfig, function(data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    },
    loadViewModel: function(name, templateConfig, callback) {
        console.log("loadViewModel", name, templateConfig);
        $.getScript(templateConfig, function(data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
};

ko.components.loaders.unshift(customLoader);
```

This successfully makes a request to load the template, which brings back some basic content. What I'm struggling with is the view model. I'm not sure what should be in the target of my JavaScript file?

I assumed that I'd want to return a function that would take some parameters, most likely a `params` object. However if I try and do this I get an error, telling me the JavaScript is invalid:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

This is the current content I've got that is producing this error:

```
return function(params) {

    console.log("myCustom.js", name, viewModelConfig);

    // Add a computed value on
    params.bookNum = ko.computed(function() {
        switch(this.title()) {
            case "A": return 1;
            case "B": return 2;
            case "C": return 3;
            default: return -1;
        }
    });

    //ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel(name, viewModelConstructor, callback);

};
```

So ultimately I'm not sure how to achieve this, but I guess there are 3 basic questions that explain the gaps in my understanding:

1. What should my "view model" JavaScript file contain exactly? A function? An object? etc...
2. Do I need to call the `ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel` at all?
3. Within my `customLoader` what should `loadViewModel()` be doing with the result of the jQuery callback? I'm not sure if I get back a JavaScript object, or just a string?

I'm open to achieve this in a different way if need be (e.g. not using jQuery but getting files a different way), but I don't want to use a module loader (e.g. require.js/curl.js in this instance).

Comment: Your script should not start with a `return`. It should be code that can be executed stand-alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets figure out what is happening...

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

> This (`$.getScript()`) is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   dataType: "script",
>   success: success
> });
> ```

And from [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> ...
>   **dataType:** ...
>         `"script"`: Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

So your code is fetched, evaluated and then would have been returned as text, but evaluation first fails because you can't `return` if you're not within a function.

So what can be done? There are several options:

1. **Use a module loader.**
   jQuery isn't a module loader, and as such it doesn't have the ability to parse fetched code and create a value / object from that code. A module loader is designed specifically for this task. It will take a script written in a specific pattern and "evaluate" it into a value (typically an object with 1 or more properties).
2. **Change your script to a legal script**
   Because it's illegal to have a `return` statement in global code, your current code fails. You could however create a named function (or a variable with a function expression) and then use that name to reference that function. It could look like this:

   ```
   function myCreateViewModel(param) {
     // whatever
   }
   ```

   And the usage would be:

   ```
   $.getScript(templateConfig, function() {
       callback(myCreateViewModel);
   });
   ```

   The downside here is that if you ever go through that code path twice in the same page, your script will overwrite the old declaration. That might not ever be a problem, but it feels dirty.
3. **Not use** `$.getScript()`**, use** `$.ajax()` **(or** `$.get()`**) with** `dataType: 'text'` **and evaluate yourself.**
   Remove the `return` from your code, and wrap it with an `eval()`. It will be evaluated as a function expression, the return value of the eval will be your function, and you could pass that directly to the callback:

   ```
   $.get({
     url: templateConfig,
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(text) {
       callback(eval(text));
     }
   });
   ```

   This will work, but it will use the frowned upon `eval()`, which is exposing you to various risks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Amit, that makes sense. I'm assuming typical module loaders use must `eval()` when they load scripts if that's the only way to execute something after it's fetched?

Comment: Probably using `new Function(...)` actually but not much of a difference. They will do it as safe as possible and with tried & tested code though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the gotcha's with eval so will take that into consideration when deciding. Soon as I prove one of these techniques work I'll accept your answer. Thank you